# What is the best way to rotate/transpose a 2d array

Tags: arrays, rotation, 2d

I am stuck on how to rotate a whole table 90 degree. So if I have a 2D array like below

```
{
 {0,0,1,0}
,{0,1,1,0}
,{0,1,0,0}
,{0,0,0,0}
}
```

and what is the best to rotate or transpose the whole table of that array into 90 degree. So the after rotate it should be look like this

```
{
 {0,0,0,0}
,{0,1,1,0}
,{0,0,1,1}
,{0,0,0,0}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets call the first array A and the second one B.
Notice that a collumn from array A becomes a row in rotated array B (first collumn in A becomes first row in B etc) and the first element of the first collumn in A becomes the last elements in the first row in B, second becomes third, third becomes second etc...
So i think the code would look like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
{
   for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
   {
      B[j][N-1-i]=A[i][j];
   }
} // where N is the size of your array
```

My "explanation" might be a bit confusing but i hope the code works

Thats assuming the size of your array A is NxN, if your array isn't square but it's sized NxM then size of your B array is MxN the only thing that changes in the code is:

```
for(int j=0; j<M; j++)
```

In the second "for"